# Common function for ByteString and ByteString.Lazy in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I implemented function that reads ByteString and converts it in hex format.
E.g. given "AA10" it converts it to [170, 16]

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS (w2c)

rHex :: BSL.ByteString -> BSL.ByteString
rHex bs
    | BSL.null bs = BSL.empty
    | BSL.null rest' = fromHex c1 `BSL.cons` BSL.empty
    | otherwise = rChunk c1 c2 `BSL.cons` rHex rest
          where (c1, rest') = (BSL.head bs, BSL.tail bs)
                (c2, rest) = (BSL.head rest', BSL.tail rest')
                rChunk c1 c2 = (fromHex c1) * 16 + fromHex c2
fromHex = fromIntegral . digitToInt . BS.w2c
```

But than I realized that I need same function but for simple ByteString, not Lazy.
The only approach I came to is something like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS (w2c)

rHex' funcs@(null, empty, cons, head, tail, fromHex) bs
    | null bs = empty
    | null rest' = fromHex c1 `cons` empty
    | otherwise = rChunk c1 c2 `cons` rHex' funcs rest
          where (c1, rest') = (head bs, tail bs)
                (c2, rest) = (head rest', tail rest')
                rChunk c1 c2 = (fromHex c1) * 16 + fromHex c2

fromHex = fromIntegral . digitToInt . BS.w2c

rHexBSL :: BSL.ByteString -> BSL.ByteString
rHexBSL = rHex' (BSL.null, BSL.empty, BSL.cons, BSL.head, BSL.tail, fromHex)

rHexBS :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
rHexBS = rHex' (BS.null, BS.empty, BS.cons, BS.head, BS.tail, fromHex)
```

So I pass all needed functions directly in `rHex'` in functions `rHexBSL` `rHexBS`.
Is there more Haskell way to make a common function for Bytestring and Bytestring.Lazy?
Maybe create type class or something?

Comment: Sorry for offtop. I'd love to learn Haskell. What would you suggest to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify this by working with `[Word8]` and using `pack` and `unpack` for each type of ByteString to get what you want -- e.g.:

```
toHex :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
toHex a b = (fromHex a) * 16 + fromHex b

hexify :: [Word8] -> [Word8] -> [Word8]
hexify (a:b:cs) = toHex a b : hexify cs
hexify [b]      = toHex 0 b
hexify []       = []

rHexBSL :: BSL.ByteString -> BSL.ByteString
rHexBSL = BSL.pack . hexify . BSL.unpack

rHexBS :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
rHexBS = BS.pack . hexify . BS.unpack
```

And I think doing it this way has a good chance of enabling fusion to make the operations efficient.

That said, it is instructive to see how Bryan does it in his [base16-bytestring` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base16-bytestring).

- [encode for Data.ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Base16.html#encode)
- [encode for Data.ByteString.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Base16-Lazy.html#encode)

Comment: I like this solution. But it seems that working with [Word8] instead of ByteString is much easier in almost all cases.

Comment: I have a feeling that the `[Word8]` view is the best when you are treating the ByteString as a list/stream of characters. But ByteString's also allow random access which doesn't mesh very well with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the `toStrict` and `fromStrict` functions from `Data.ByteString.Lazy` to convert back and forth between strict and lazy types. In this particular case:

```
rHexBS = BSL.toStrict . hHexBSL . BSL.fromStrict
```

Comment: Agree, this solution is much more elegant than my one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class to hand in the lens package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lens.html#v:packedBytes .  So given user5402's code
for hexify, which I guess should be

```
 hexify :: [Word8] -> [Word8]
 hexify (a:b:cs) = toHex a b : hexify cs
 hexify [b]      = [toHex 0 b]
 hexify []       = []
```

you will find (with `Control.Lens.under` also in scope) that you can write

```
 rHex :: IsByteString b => b -> b 
 rHex = under packedBytes hexify
```

and do various other things like that. It might be more trouble than it's worth; I mention it because a suitable class is there. `under packedBytes f` just encodes the tiresome `pack . f . unpack` business, but covers both senses of `pack`.